# Split table with header to print it out

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, printing

I'm reading some data from MySQL with PHP and trying to print (to paper) the data on a `<table>` but I need to split the `<table>` to leave just 30 row per sheet and each sheet has to have a header inside that `<table>` I'm doing the header with `<thead>` but I don't know how to split the `<table>` , cause I don't know how many rows will return MySQL

I've tried with jQuery something like this(not this):

```
if($('#my_table tbody tr').length > 30) {
    $('#div_page').html($('#my_table thead') + $('#my_table').slice(0 , 30));
}
```

this only take from row 0 to row 30, so if I do it again it takes from row 31 to row 60 (for jQuery the first 30 do not exists now cause it was printed to the document)
so that script takes 30 by 30 the rows from the original `<table>`

but I don't know how to make jQuery repeat that script til all the rows have been printed

I don't care if it has to be done with jQuery, PHP, JavaScript or another language but what I need is it to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your if statement in a while that tests for length greater than 0.  and then use an else to get the remainder lines at the end.

```
while ($('#my_table tbody tr').length > 0) {
    if($('#my_table tbody tr').length > 30) {
        $('#div_page').html($('#my_table thead') + $('#my_table').slice(0 , 30));
    }
    else {
    //handle rows less than 30 if its the last iteration
    }
}
```